# BS 3.0 Sticky Footer with 100% height child divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the sticky footer method for Bootstrap 3.0 as described in their example. I have it working fine and that is not what I am struggling with.

It calls for the wrapper to have the following:

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
/* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
/* Negative indent footer by its height */
margin: 0 auto -60px;
/* Pad bottom by footer height */
padding: 0 0 60px;
}
```

Now I am trying to have some 100% height containers inside that and I can't because there is a height of auto on the parent. Is there a way to get around this and keep my sticky footer? I want to put 100% height containers that stretch so I can put backgrounds in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this solution fits your needs, but it involves absolute positioning a div behind the sidebar and making it stretch the height of `#wrap` by setting `top` and `bottom` to 0. It essentially inherits the height while avoiding explicitly declaring a height property. The only potential problem would be if you have other elements that are above the sidebar (i.e. headers) since the div will also be stretch behind those as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/qaB8D/

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
}

aside, #words {
    /* This is just so the sidebar stays left, and the text stays right */
    display: table-cell; 
}

aside {
    width: 100px;
}

aside:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -10;
}

/* include Sticky Footer code/*
```